# Data from Database into the table (can't figure out how to do layout)

Tags: php, html, mysqli, html-table

This is my code (horrible one):

```
<?php

include 'connect/con.php';

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, vidTitle FROM newsvid");
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT imgCover, vidSD FROM newsvid");
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT published FROM newsvid");




echo "<table width=\"600\" border=\"1\"><tbody>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo '<td width=\"10%\"><a href="details.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['id'].'</a></td>';
  echo "<td width=\"90%\">" . $row['vidTitle'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody></table>";


echo "<table width=\"600\" border=\"1\"><tbody>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td width=\"40%\">" . $row['imgCover'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td width=\"60%\">" . $row['vidSD'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody></table>";




echo "<table width=\"600\" border=\"1\"><tbody>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td >" . $row['published'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody></table>";



mysqli_close($con);
?>



</body>
</html>
```

The question is how to show data from database in this layout:

```
--------------------------------
-id----------vidTitle-----------
--------------------------------
-imgCover------vidSD------------
--------------------------------
----------published-------------
```

So every time I will add more data , another block like I showed before will add up under existing one.
........................................................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to write 3 queries. You could do that with only one select, and then put all the echos inside a `while`. That way you're writing, it would run all the ids and titles first, then it would put a table after the table, with cover and `vidSD`.

Try to make a single query:

`SELECT id, vidTitle, imgCover, vidSD, published  FROM newsvid`

That way you will have, on each row returned from database, all the information about the same row.

Now, running a while is the same as you're doing, just adapting some HTML:

```
echo "<table width='600' border='1'><tbody>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo '<td width=\"10%\"><a href="details.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['id'].'</a></td>';
  echo "<td width=\"90%\">" . $row['vidTitle'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td width=\"40%\">" . $row['imgCover'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td width=\"60%\">" . $row['vidSD'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td colspan='2'>" . $row['published'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

You may want to order it too. Adding `ORDER BY id DESC`, would do that.

Comment: EVERYTHING is looks cool BUT the main problem that in the table width 10% and in another TR where td 40% will not work(((

Comment: All table will looks like 50% by 50% and if you change is to 10% by 90% nothing changes they are still the same..